# jQuery to control mutually exclusive and conditional checkboxes

Tags: c#, jquery, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I need four checkboxes - A, B, C, D.

A, B and C are mutually exclusive and so only one of them may be checked at a time.

D may only be checked if C is also checked.

Is it possible to add a jQuery script on the click or change event to enforce these rules?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Any specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a JSFiddle for your solution.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z49h0ggv/2/)

```
And code:
<input type="checkbox" id="a"> A<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="b"> B<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="c"> C<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="d"> D<br/>

<script>
$('#a').click(function(){
   $('#b').attr("checked", false);
   $('#c').attr("checked", false);
   $('#d').attr("checked", false);
});

$('#b').click(function(){
   $('#a').attr("checked", false);
   $('#c').attr("checked", false);
   $('#d').attr("checked", false);
});

$('#c').click(function(){
   $('#a').attr("checked", false);
   $('#b').attr("checked", false);
   $('#d').attr("checked", false);
});

$('#d').click(function(){
    if($('#c').prop('checked')){
        $('#d').attr("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));
    }else{
       $('#d').attr("checked", false);
    }
   $('#a').attr("checked", false);
   $('#b').attr("checked", false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectly for me, really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I wonder if you can help me further on this? I have some code which gathers the value(s) of the checked boxes into a string: 'var result = $.map($("input[name='group']:checked"), function (e,i) { return e.value; });' which works great elsewhere but not in this case. Here even though the first value is unchecked by jQuery when the second is checked the string being returned retains the unchecked value. Can you tell me a better way to get the correct value from this checkbox group?